# Find height of element when dom subtree is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, height, hidden

First of all, I have looked at loads of related questions, both on SO and in other places - but none is addressing my issue (unfortunately).

I have a dynamically built DOM substree about 10-levels deep and a complex javascript code that shows or hides pieces of that subtree (or the entire subtree).  There's another code that can change text of various `div` elements somewhere inside that subtree (somewhere means anywhere from level 1 to level 10).  Further, individual nodes inside the subtree can also be shown or hidden.

To make a long story short, whenever the text is changed, I need to figure out the new height of the corresponding div.  Unfortunately, when the text changes, the actual div is "visible" within the context of its parent and usually its parent's parent - but not within the context of the whole subtree - hence the height is returned as 0.

Pretty much all solutions center around making the div visible, measuring its height, then hiding it again.  To adopt this solution to my issue, I would have to take the div in question, then traverse the dom tree upward from it, check whether the corresponding parents are hidden or not, change their visibility, continue upward until I got everything shown, then measure the height of my div, then revert the visibility of the elements that I changed.

Apart from being a nightmare to implement, it sounds EXTREMELY slow.  So, is there any solution for getting the height of a div, that in itself is visible within its parent, but has several of its (not direct) parents hidden?  I'm happy with either jQuery or a plain javascript solution.

Comment: Do you have some code to share?

Comment: @AamirAfridi I certainly have my code - about 3,000 lines of jquery code with another 1,000 of CSS - but I don't believe any code is required in this question.

Comment: instead of hiding elements using `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, try hiding them using `position:fixed; left:100%; top:100%;`

Comment: @Pete I don't think it's a good idea, because the entire tree is carefully positioned - each level. And the positioning is auto-adjusted on window resizing and scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** to get the height of the element on the page if you don't show it anyhow. In your case, if you say that the DOM tree is very complicated and the element may be positioned dynamically, you definitely need to show all hidden parents and the element itself to get its size. The operation may take long time (in terms of milliseconds), so I'd add an overlay for the end users.

```
var $overlay = $('<div />').text('loading...').css({
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        position: 'fixed',
        color: '#fff',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        zIndex: 100
    }).appendTo('body'),
    $element = $('.element'),
    $parent = $element.parents('.hidden').addClass('shown').show().last(),
    height = $element.height();

$('body').append(height);
$parent.find('.shown').addBack().hide();
$overlay.remove();
```

The only possible drawback I see is in images which browser *may* load on display and change the height of the element some time later after the actual height was calculated.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZuGd7/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had a project where I had to do the same. I've created a very basic working example here ( http://jsbin.com/zujoj/3/ ) on how you can implement this, even though mine end up being more complex, it's based in the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#myButton").on("click", function(){

      // this is a helper variable
      var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1) + 1);

      // using some dummie text placeholders
      var data = $(".myText" + i).html();

      // this is how I get the height, you see the textContainerStyle? Use yours instead
      var height = $(".textContainerStyle").html(data).height();

      // finally you get the value
      $("#lastHeight").val(height);

  });

});
```

Some html to help with the example:

```
  <input id="lastHeight" type="text" value="0">

  <div class="textContainerStyle">

  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <button id="myButton">Click me</button>
      <div class="hidden myText1"><p>Lorem ipsum colorom dolorem morem</p></div>
      <div class="hidden myText2"><p>Lorem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem</p></div>      
      <div class="hidden myText3"><p>Lorem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem</p></div>
      <div class="hidden myText4"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
      <div class="hidden myText5"><p>Lorem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem. Lorem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem. Lorem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem orem ipsum colorom dolorem morem</p></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And finally, but not less important the style to help achieving this:

```
.textContainerStyle {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to get into the hassle of toggling the visibility of the parent hierarchy, then the best approach is to depend upon 
`window.getComputedStyle(<elem>)` to get you the desired dimensions. getComputedStyle works irrespective of visibility state of the element (atleast in FF, Chrome, IE at the time of writing)

So in your case this would be:

```
var height = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(<id of element in question>)).getPropertyValue("height");

// height would always be in px, except in case of IE where it could be em's depending upon the style usage.
height = parseFloat(height);
```